# Power BI V2 - Auditing or Usage metrics

Tags: powerbi

what kind of auditing is possible in Power BI V2?

Also what is the difference between V1 and V2?

what are the steps to migrate existing V1 workspace to V2?

Answer (score 0):

The V2 workspaces handle security differently. V1 workspaces automatically creat O365 modern groups behind the scenes. They also have different membership roles and require that all non-admin members in a workspace be either edit or read-only (so you can't have some that can edit and some that only read). And they didn't sync with AD groups.

The V2 workspaces do not create O365 modern groups. They have contributors and members (read-only is not yet available yet). In the new workspaces, you can assign roles to security groups, distribution lists, Office 365 groups, and individuals.

Once the new workspaces are GA, you will be able to opt in to automatically migrate your V1 workspaces to v2 workspaces.

I don't think auditing will be any different. You'll have to let me know in the comments if there is something specific you are looking for. [Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-auditing) in PBI is based upon events (viewing a report, sharing a dashboard), but this includes adding a member to a workspace. If you aren't an admin, you won't be able to see audit logs by default.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In V1, it is using o365 admin panel for auditing. will it be same in V2?

Comment: Yes, same admin panel.